# Cartesian product of three sets when a set contains a subset and duplicates.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If there are three sets

```
A = {1, 2}
B = {1, 2, {1, 2}}
C = {4, 5}
```

The product of these sets would be:

```
A x B = { (1,1), (1,2), (1,(1,2)), (2,1), (2,2), (2,(1,2)) }
```

Then

```
A x B x C = { (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,2,4), (1,2,5), (1,(1,2),4), (1,(1,2),5), (2,1,4), (2,1,5), (2,2,4), (2,2,5), (2,(1,2),4), (2,(1,2),5) }
```

Is my understanding of this correct?

Edit from comments:

```
A x B = { (1,1), (1,2), (1,{1,2}), (2,1), (2,2), (2,{1,2}) }

A x B x C = { (1,1,4), (1,1,5), (1,2,4), (1,2,5), (1,{1,2},4), (1,{1,2},5), (2,1,4), (2,1,5), (2,2,4), (2,2,5), (2,{1,2},4), (2,{1,2},5) }
```

Comment: Replace $(1,2)$ by $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Replace $\{1,2\}$ by some symbol, say $z$, then expand as above, then replace $z$...

Comment: @RafaelHolanda Ah, so like I've done in the edit?

Comment: @NuMs yes. Now it is correct.